# Codepen : " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( " in browser console when other environments don't throw errors

Tags: javascript

I keep having 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( at pen.js:121
on my code on codepen, which causes it to abort execution, although it is working in Brackets & other editors and other people browsers.

Here is the link : http://codepen.io/N0bl3/full/EKPYZB/

```
/*jshint esnext:true, browser:true*/
var TICTACTOE = {
  grid: {
    size: 3,
    color: "#000000",
    plays: []
  },
  players: [{
    name: "Cross",
    symbol: "X"
  }, {
    name: "Circle",
    symbol: "O"
  }],
  currentPlayer: 1,
  played: 0,
  drawGrid(ctx) {

    for (var i = 0; i <= this.grid.size; i++) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
      ctx.lineWidth = "1";
      ctx.moveTo(0, 200 / 3 * i);
      ctx.lineTo(200, 200 / 3 * i);
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(200 / 3 * i, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(200 / 3 * i, 200);
      ctx.stroke();
    }

  },
  drawSign(ctx, symbol, x, y) {
    //Canvas draw
    if (symbol === "X") {
      ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
      ctx.lineWidth = "1";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(200 / 3 * x, 200 / 3 * y);
      ctx.lineTo(200 / 3 * (x + 1), 200 / 3 * (y + 1));
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(200 / 3 * (x + 1), 200 / 3 * y);
      ctx.lineTo(200 / 3 * x, 200 / 3 * (y + 1));
      ctx.stroke();
    } else {
      ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
      ctx.lineWidth = "1";
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(200 / 3 * x + 200 / 3 / 2, 200 / 3 * y + 200 / 3 / 2, 200 / 3 / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    alert("Drawing: " + x + " " + y);
  },
  init() {
    var c = document.getElementById("TICTACTOE");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    this.drawGrid(ctx);
    c.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      var x = event.clientX;
      var y = event.clientY;
      var sizeSquare = 200 / 3;
      var legal = false;
      if (x < sizeSquare && y < sizeSquare && typeof TICTACTOE.grid.plays[0] !== "number") {
        TICTACTOE.grid.plays[0] = TICTACTOE.currentPlayer;
        TICTACTOE.drawSign(ctx, TICTACTOE.players[TICTACTOE.grid.plays[0]].symbol, 0, 0);
        legal = true;

      } else if (x >= sizeSquare && x < sizeSquare * 2 && y < sizeSquare && typeof TICTACTOE.grid.plays[1] !== "number") {
        TICTACTOE.grid.plays[1] = TICTACTOE.currentPlayer;
        TICTACTOE.drawSign(ctx, TICTACTOE.players[TICTACTOE.grid.plays[1]].symbol, 1, 0);
        legal = true;

      } else if (x >= sizeSquare * 2 && y < sizeSquare && typeof TICTACTOE.grid.plays[2] !== "number") {
        TICTACTOE.grid.plays[2] = TICTACTOE.currentPlayer;
        TICTACTOE.drawSign(ctx, TICTACTOE.players[TICTACTOE.grid.plays[2]].symbol, 2, 0);
        legal = true;

      } else if (x < sizeSquare && y >= sizeSquare && y < sizeSquare * 2 && typeof TICTACTOE.grid.plays[3] !== "number") {
        TICTACTOE.grid.plays[3] = TICTACTOE.currentPlayer;
        TICTACTOE.drawSign(ctx, TICTACTOE.players[TICTACTOE.grid.plays[3]].symbol, 0, 1);
        legal = true;

      } else if (x >= sizeSquare && x < sizeSquare * 2 && y >= sizeSquare && y < sizeSquare * 2 && typeof TICTACTOE.grid.plays[4] !== "number") {
        TICTACTOE.grid.plays[4] = TICTACTOE.currentPlayer;
        TICTACTOE.drawSign(ctx, TICTACTOE.players[TICTACTOE.grid.plays[4]].symbol, 1, 1);
        legal = true;

      } else if (x >= sizeSquare * 2 && y >= sizeSquare && y < sizeSquare * 2 && typeof TICTACTOE.grid.plays[5] !== "number") {
        TICTACTOE.grid.plays[5] = TICTACTOE.currentPlayer;
        TICTACTOE.drawSign(ctx, TICTACTOE.players[TICTACTOE.grid.plays[5]].symbol, 2, 1);
        legal = true;

      } else if (x < sizeSquare && y >= sizeSquare * 2 && typeof TICTACTOE.grid.plays[6] !== "number") {
        TICTACTOE.grid.plays[6] = TICTACTOE.currentPlayer;
        TICTACTOE.drawSign(ctx, TICTACTOE.players[TICTACTOE.grid.plays[6]].symbol, 0, 2);
        legal = true;

      } else if (x >= sizeSquare && y >= sizeSquare * 2 && x < sizeSquare * 2 && typeof TICTACTOE.grid.plays[7] !== "number") {
        TICTACTOE.grid.plays[7] = TICTACTOE.currentPlayer;
        TICTACTOE.drawSign(ctx, TICTACTOE.players[TICTACTOE.grid.plays[7]].symbol, 1, 2);
        legal = true;

      } else if (x >= sizeSquare * 2 && y >= sizeSquare * 2 && typeof TICTACTOE.grid.plays[8] !== "number") {
        TICTACTOE.grid.plays[8] = TICTACTOE.currentPlayer;
        TICTACTOE.drawSign(ctx, TICTACTOE.players[TICTACTOE.grid.plays[8]].symbol, 2, 2);
        legal = true;
      } else {
        legal = false;
      }

      if (legal) {
        TICTACTOE.played++;
        TICTACTOE.checkEnd();
      } else {
        alert("This move is not allowed");
      }
      TICTACTOE.currentPlayer = TICTACTOE.currentPlayer === 1 ? 0 : 1;
      document.getElementById("player").textContent = TICTACTOE.currentPlayer;
    });
  },
  checkEnd() {
    if (this.played >= 5) {
      //Verifier les possibilités gagnantes 0 2 4 fonctionne pourquoi? et 023
      var plays = this.grid.plays;
      if (
        (plays[0] === plays[1] && plays[1] === plays[2] && typeof plays[0] === "number") ||
        (plays[0] === plays[4] && plays[4] === plays[8] && typeof plays[0] === "number") ||
        (plays[0] === plays[3] && plays[3] === plays[6] && typeof plays[0] === "number") ||
        (plays[1] === plays[4] && plays[4] === plays[7] && typeof plays[1] === "number") ||
        (plays[2] === plays[4] && plays[4] === plays[6] && typeof plays[2] === "number") ||
        (plays[2] === plays[5] && plays[5] === plays[8] && typeof plays[2] === "number") ||
        (plays[3] === plays[4] && plays[4] === plays[5] && typeof plays[3] === "number") ||
        (plays[6] === plays[7] && plays[7] === plays[8] && typeof plays[6] === "number")
      ) {
        alert("The winner is: " + this.players[this.currentPlayer].name);
        window.location.reload();
      } else if (this.played >= 9) {
        alert("Match end! No one wins this time!");
        window.location.reload();
      }
    }
  }
};
document.getElementById("player").textContent = TICTACTOE.currentPlayer;
TICTACTOE.init();
```

& the HTML :

```
<canvas id="TICTACTOE" width="200" height="200">Your browser doesn't support HTML 5 canvas. Consider upgrading or changing your browser</canvas>
<p>Hello!</p>
<p id="player"></p>
```

What is wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Codepen must not like `window.location.reload()` and may strip out parts of that code.

Comment: @Colin is right. use `window.location=window.location;` instead.

Comment: `drawGrid(ctx) {` should be `drawGrid: function (ctx) {` (same with drawSign)

Comment: @Colin thanks a lot! It was the problem. I'll report to their technical staff however as this should not be an issue imo.

Comment: @Brunt it is ES6 syntax and is supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just formalizing my comment with an "official" answer. The error was being thrown on the following line:

```
// ...
alert("The winner is: " + this.players[this.currentPlayer].name);
window.(); // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
// ...
```

Whereas, the source code contains the following:

```
// ...
alert("The winner is: " + this.players[this.currentPlayer].name);
window.location.reload();
// ...
```

Clearly, codepen does not like the `window.location.reload()` calls (?) and is stripping that code out.

Note that any errors/exceptions that appear in your browser's dev tools usually include a link you can click to be taken to the offending line of source code.

Comment: Interesting. They should make a topic on their troubleshooting IMHO